# Reformatting an excel sheet in R

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel file that has multiple sheets. each sheet looks like this with some excess data at the bottom

```
    A      B     C    D.... 
1   time  USA   USA   USA   
2          MD     CA   PX   
3         pork  peas  nuts 
4   jan-11  4      2      2
5   feb-11  4      9      3
6   mar-11  8      8      3
```

.
.
workbook1|workbook2.....

The file is 11 mb, but when I try to use

```
sheet<-readWorksheetFromFile("excelfile.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

I get

```
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space
```

For each work sheet the data takes up different number for rows and columns, I want to write something that produces this for each sheet.

I am trying to convert each column into

```
country state product unit time 
USA     MD     pork    3    jan-11
USA     MD     pork    3    feb-11
USA     MD     pork    3    mar-11
...
..
.
```

Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: So is your question about reading the data in or reshaping the data once you have done so?

Comment: I guess its both, I am still trying to get R to read the workbook without saying that its out of memory, also thanks for editing the post, this is my first time asking a question.

Comment: have you tried `read.xls` in the `gdata` package? I think a 11MB file shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You have a few problems here. Multi-line headers might be pretty in Excel, but pretty horrible in any data analysis software. Do you get the same error with all spreadsheets? Or just this one?

Comment: I have not tried the gdata package, I will try that now. As for excel format, yes it is very horrible but I cannot even read the file as R runs out of memory trying to read 1 sheet in an 11 mb file.

Comment: installed the gdata package and using sheet<-read.xls("fewsnetafrica.xlsx",sheet =1) but its already been 10 minutes and its still running. I have however tried to copy and paste a sheet without formulas into a new excel file and saved it as a csv. That helps it load fast with the wierd excel formatting. I think maybe the formulas is what makes it run slow?

Comment: Did you read the XLConnect FAQ? It suggests setting 'options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")' before loading RJava/XLConnect.

Comment: How many sheets do you have? There are some scripts to automatically output CSV files for all sheets in an Excel workbook. That might be useful if you say `read.csv` works. By the way, ping a user here with by adding an "@" before their name, like @BaconDoggie. That way, they'll know when you've added new info that might help solve the problem.

Comment: Not that this directly answers your question, but the `data.table` package has a very efficient `fread` function, that would be useful if @AnandaMahto's point about headers is addressed. I can open 100MB files (saved as .csv) in just a few seconds this way. e.g. `require(data.table); dtable<-fread("path\\file.csv")`

Answer (score 2):

If your spreadsheet is full of formulas, you might need to convert those to values to get them to be read in easily. Otherwise, I would suggest using a [tool like this one](http://cwestblog.com/2013/04/12/batch-excel-to-csv-converter-application/) (among others out there) to convert all the sheets in a workbook to CSV files and work from there.

If you've gotten that far, here's something that can be tried for the "reshaping" part of your question. Here, we'll assume that "A" actually represents a CSV file, the contents of which are the six lines shown as sample data in your question:

```
## Create some sample data
A <- tempfile()
writeLines(sep="\n", con = A,
           text = c("time,  USA,   USA,   USA",
                    ",   MD,    CA,    PX",
                    ", pork,  peas,  nuts",
                    "jan-11,    4,     2,     2",
                    "feb-11,    4,     9,     3",
                    "mar-11,    8,     8,     3"))
```

The first thing I would do is read in the headers and the data separately. To read the headers separately, use `nrows` to specify the number of rows that contain the header information. To read the data separately, specify `skip` to skip the header rows.

```
B <- read.csv(A, header = FALSE, skip = 3, strip.white = TRUE)
Bnames <- read.csv(A, header = FALSE, nrows = 3, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Use `apply` to `paste` the header rows together to form the names for the resulting `data.frame`:

```
names(B) <- apply(Bnames, 2, function(x) paste(x[x != ""], collapse = "_"))
B
#     time USA_MD_pork USA_CA_peas USA_PX_nuts
# 1 jan-11           4           2           2
# 2 feb-11           4           9           3
# 3 mar-11           8           8           3
```

Now comes the part of converting the data from a "wide" to a "long" format. There are many ways to do this, some using base R too, but the most direct is to use `melt` and `colsplit` from the "reshape2" package:

```
library(reshape2)
BL <- melt(B, id.vars="time")
cbind(BL[c("time", "value")], 
      colsplit(BL$variable, "_", 
               c("country", "state", "product")))
#     time value country state product
# 1 jan-11     4     USA    MD    pork
# 2 feb-11     4     USA    MD    pork
# 3 mar-11     8     USA    MD    pork
# 4 jan-11     2     USA    CA    peas
# 5 feb-11     9     USA    CA    peas
# 6 mar-11     8     USA    CA    peas
# 7 jan-11     2     USA    PX    nuts
# 8 feb-11     3     USA    PX    nuts
# 9 mar-11     3     USA    PX    nuts
```

Comment: Quick question, How would this change if some values where missing, like some state values were blank i get this error  Error in substring(string, start, end) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<99>te D'<49>voire_Abidjan_Adjame_Rice_Retail_kg_XOF'

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, XLConnect is unlikely to work in your application. I can confirm that on a system with 8GB RAM, running Win 7 64bit and  64bit R 3.0.2, XLConnect fails with a 22MB `.xlsx` file,  with the same error that you are getting. As @Ista pointed out, and as explained [here](http://www.mirai-solutions.com/site/index.cfm?id_art=69890&actMenuItemID=31456&vsprache/EN/Mirai_Solutions___XLConnect_.cfm), after restarting R and *before doing anything else*:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4096m")
library(XLConnect)
wb    <- loadWorkbook("myWorkBook.xlsx")
sheet <- readWorksheet(wb,"Data")
```

avoids the error. However, the import still *takes more than an hour*(!!).

In contrast, as @Gaffi pointed out, once the sheet "Data" is saved to a csv file (~7MB), it can be imported as follows:

```
library(data.table)
system.time(sheet <- fread("Data.csv"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.84    0.00    0.86
```

in less than 1 second. In my test case `sheet` has 6 columns and ~376,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this "second answer", but you really had two questions... @Ananda's solution for reshaping your data is extremely elegant. This is just another way to think about it.

If you transpose the input matrix you get a new matrix, where the first column is country, the second column is city, the third column is "type" (for lack of a better term), and the actual data is in the other columns (so, there is one additional column for every "time").

So a different approach is to transpose first and then melt the new matrix. This avoids creating all the concatenated column names and splitting them back later. The problem is that `melt.data.frame` is exceptionally inefficient with a very large number of columns (which you would have here). So doing it this way would bbe 10X *slower* than @Ananda's approach.

A solution is to use `melt.array` (just call `melt(...)` with an array rather than a data frame). As shown below, this approach is ~20X faster, with larger datasets (yours was 11MB).

```
library(reshape)        # for melt(...)
library(microbenchmark) # for microbenchmark(...)

# this is just to model your situation with more realistic size
# create a large data frame (250 columns of country, city, type; 1000 rows of time)
df <- rep(c("USA","UK","FR","CHN","GER"),each=50)   # time + 250 columns
df <- rbind(df,rep(c(c("NY","SF","CHI","BOS","LA")),each=10))
df <- rbind(df,rep(c("pork","peas","nuts","fruit","other")))
df <- rbind(df,matrix(sample(1:1000,250*1000,replace=T),ncol=250))
df <- cbind(c("time","","",
               as.character(as.Date(1:1000,origin="2010-01-01"))),df)
df <- data.frame(df)    # big warning here about duplicated row names; not important

# @Ananda'a approach:
transform.orig <- function(df){
  B        <- df[-(1:3),]
  Bnames   <- df[1:3,]
  names(B) <- apply(Bnames, 2, function(x) paste(x[x != ""], collapse = "_"))
  BL       <- melt(B, id.vars="time")
  final    <- cbind(BL[c("time", "value")], 
                         colsplit(BL$variable, "_", 
                                  c("country", "state", "product")))
  return(final)
}

# transpose approach:
transform.new <- function(df) {
  zz           <- t(df)
  times        <- t(zz[1,4:ncol(zz)])
  colnames(zz) <- c("country","city","type", times)
  data  <- melt(zz[-1,-(1:3)],varnames=c("id","time"))
  final <- cbind(country=rep(zz[-1,1],each=ncol(zz)-3),
                 city   =rep(zz[-1,2],each=ncol(zz)-3),
                 type   =rep(zz[-1,3],each=ncol(zz)-3),
                 data[,-1])
  return(final)
}

# benchmark
microbenchmark(transform.orig(df),transform.new(df), times=5, unit="s")
Unit: seconds
               expr       min        lq   median         uq        max neval
 transform.orig(df) 9.2511679 9.6986330 9.889457 10.1518191 10.3354328     5
  transform.new(df) 0.4383197 0.4724145 0.474212  0.5815531  0.6886383     5
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading the data from excel, try the **openxlsx** package. It uses c++ instead of java, and better handles larger excel files.

To reshape your data look at the **tidyr** package. The **gather** function could help you out.